# how to redirect subdomain to subdir with .htaccess without changing URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

There is a domain/subdomain `example.com`/`www.example.com` (obviously they both point to `/public_html`) and website placed in this dir works perfectly. I've created subdir `/public_html/wwwnew`, and subdomain `wwwnew.example.com`. I want this subdomain to point to this subfolder, but I don't want to change URL typed by user (`wwwnew.example.com`). Of course I need to use `.htaccess`.

My current `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(wwwnew.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wwwnew [L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [L]
```

Currently when I type in `wwwnew.example.com` URL changes to `wwwnew.example.com/wwwnew`. I want this `/wwwnew` to disappear...

Any help?

Comment: "Of course I need to use `.htaccess`" - why is that? Do you not have access to the server config?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wwwnew [L]
> ```

If `wwwnew` is a physical subdirectory (which you say it is) then you should append a trailing slash on the end of the `RewriteRule` *susbtition* (and preferably the index document as well). If you don't then mod_dir will append the slash for you (in order to "fix" the URL) and in doing so triggers an external 301 redirect (which you appear to be seeing). Although this would be a redirect to `wwwnew.example.com/wwwnew/` (with a trailing slash), not `wwwnew.example.com/wwwnew` as you've stated in the question.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(wwwnew.)?example.com$
> ```

However, your condition rewrites requests for both the apex domain and the subdomain. In your description you only describe rewriting from the subdomain, not the apex domain (in which you have another site).

So, try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wwwnew\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^$ wwwnew/ [L]
```

There's no need for `(/)?` in `.htaccess`. Although, preferably, you should rewrite directly to the document (ie. index document) that you want to handle this request (otherwise mod_dir must do this for you). For example:

```
RewriteRule ^$ wwwnew/index.php [L]
```

You will need to clear your browser cache, as the erroneous *redirect* to `/wwwnew` will have been cached by the browser.

**UPDATE:**

However, the above only rewrites requests for the bare subdomain, without any URL-path (as stated in the question). In order to rewrite *any* requests for this subdomain (eg. `wwwnew.example.com/<something>`) to the subdirectory then you would need to do something like the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wwwnew\.example\.com
RewriteRule !^wwwnew/ wwwnew/index.php [L]
```

This ensures we don't get a rewrite loop.

Comment: Big thanks! Your rule worked. However...I've put there WrodPress-based solution. You've asked "what should happen to requests wwwnew.example.com/something" which I guess will be generated by WordPress. So all of the request should be without /wwwnew...Can you help?

To be honest I'm network admin and was asked to prepare this subfolder and subdomain. Guy that created our new site asked for it. I don't have access to apache. That's external hosting provider. I was told by consultant, that manipulation of htaccess is the only way.

Comment: If this answer worked for you then please mark it as accepted to remove it from the unanswered question queue and you can also upvote answers you find useful. Thanks, much appreciated :)